# Fetch JS retreive eror response

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am calling an API which could potentially return a 40x response with an associated error body which I want to use. I've tried to use a check if the `response.ok()` and then throw a error with the `response.json()`  which a catch statement will handle however when the catch runs it will only have a `Promise {<pending>}`.

This was my resulting attempt which returned a promise to `setError()`.

```
getAPI(path)
      .then((result) => {
        setResult(result);
      })
      .catch((resError) => {
        setError(`${resError}`);
      });

function getAPI(path) {
  return fetch(
    `http://localhost:3000/${path}`,
    {
      method: "GET",
    }
  ).then((res) => {
    if (res.ok) {
      return res.json();
    } else {
      throw res.json();
    }
  });
}
```

If in my getAPI I simply return res.json() and not check for a success error code then I get the body of the 400 error however I have no way of checking that the response had an error code.

```
function getAPI(path) {
  return fetch(
    `http://localhost:3000/${path}`,
    {
      method: "GET",
    }
  ).then((res) => {
    res.json();
  });
}
```

I can see twhen the fetch is resolved `res` contains the following attributes.

```
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 400
statusText: "Bad Request"
type: "cors"
url: "http://localhost:3000/"
```

Comment: Can you log `res` and see what all attributes it consists of?

Comment: I've added the res to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

> ```js
> } else {
>   throw res.json();
> }
> ```

`res.json()` returns a promise which will not be resolved by `throw`.

In your `else` block, try

```js
return res.json().then(err => throw err)
```

or

```js
return res.json().then(err => Promise.reject(err))
```

Comment: Thanks @Phil The first option worked, the second gave me this result in the catch `TypeError: PromiseReject called on non-object    at reject (<anonymous>)`

Comment: Oops, I thought `Promise.reject` was safe to pass around like that. Guess not. I'll update